# Rotate section box

Tags: autodesk-forge

The section box is currently not able to be rotated natively (as I see it at least). Because very few models/objects are actually placed perpendicular to X/Y I have been trying to look into a method for doing this.

Does anyone know of a method for doing this?
Anyone know if this is something that are being considered implemented in the near future?

It would be nice to include the rotation gizmo from the normal section plane, or have the box natively be added to follow the orientation of the face selected when creating it through the viewer UI.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the section box is not possible today, and as far as I know there are no plans for that, either.

Depending on what your exact use case is, you could potentially achieve what you need by rotating the **model** (using `model.setPlacementTransform(xform)`) and not the section box.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and potential idea. In this case the idea is unfortunately not a solution, so I will just have to wait and hope for the rotation of the section box to be introduced.